# Properly formatting a text table in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io

Currently I'm trying to write a program in Visual Basic to output a text based table based on a set amount of results.

I'm trying to incorporate something like the below C++ code to properly format the table but can't figure out what code to use in Visual Basic to achieve a similar effect. (I know that `cout` and `endl` are particular to C++ but I'm hoping that there exists an alternative for VB)

```
cout << endl << "Month#      Interest Amount     Monthly Amount     New Amount" << endl;

int counter = 1;
while (counter <= length * 12) {
    cout << right << setw(6) << counter; // Month Counter
}
```

Without giving too much of the code and making this a mess, this is what I have.

```
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim strParticipantList As String = ""

    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter

    strOutput = Trim(eventName & " Final Results") & vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
                "Total Number of Participants: " + TotalParticipants & vbNewLine

    For Each storage As StopwatchStorage In _storage
        strParticipantList &= storage.ParticipantOrder.Text
    Next
```

The idea is that I will loop through each item in storage and properly format the row as a string formatted like the `cout` stated from the C++ code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904923/how-can-i-format-a-string-into-a-fixed-width-field-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Using outFile As New IO.StreamWriter("File Path Here")
    outFile.WriteLine("{0} Final Results", eventName)
    outFile.WriteLine()
    outFile.WriteLine("Total Number of Participants: {0}", TotalParticipants)
    outFile.WriteLine()

    'Using C++ example with some made-up variable names to show how this can work
    outFile.WriteLine("Month#      Interest Amount     Monthly Amount     New Amount")
    For Each storage As StopwatchStorage In _storage
        outFile.WriteLine("{0,-6} {1,-20} {2,-18} {3,-14}", _
            storage.Month, storage.Interest, storage.MonthlyTotal, storage.NewTotal)
    Next
End Using
```

The `{x}` placeholders mark indices in the later parameters for substitution. An `{m,n}` placeholder uses the portion after the comma to set the width of the item. A positive number is left-aligned for that many characters, a negative number is right-aligned. Here's the [documentation for how it works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Already answered my own question with that, this works perfectly! (Just wish there was someway to Center Align stuff)